# Adding a sink drain to washing machine drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, washing-machine, kitchen-sink

I am installing a kitchenette and need to add a drain for a kitchen sink, the problem is the closest drain is the washing machine standpipe.

The kitchenette will be a L shape with the sink being on the left side under a window, the standpipe is about 3/4 of the way down the right side.

The standpipe drains to the right through a P trap and then into the concrete floor with what I am 90% sure is a vent pipe extending up from the sanitary T (See first photo)

Adding the drain would be easy if the washing machine was on the right side of the sub-stack but sadly it's not and the sink has to be on the left side of the kitchenette (I really tried to get a design with the sink on the right to work but sadly it's a small complicated space).

My idea is to move the washing machine standpipe up and maybe over a little, use a WYE where the leg of the existing P trap is and run the line over and around the corner to the new sink. Then loop the vent back around the corner and connect to what I am pretty sure is the vent for the washing machine. (See second photo)

So I guess my question is, am I thinking about this right, or is there an easier way? (besides laying a new pipe in the concrete)

[image: Current drain setup]

[image: Design Idea]

Comment: that would not be advisable

Comment: That sounds like it could be an answer, @Ruskes, if you expand on it and explain why. Otherwise, it's not particularly helpful.